# Launching a canvas as intent

Tags: android, android-intent, canvas, manifest

Friends i have an activity "myGame" which uses setContentView(myCanvas).
Now whenever my MainActivity launches myGame as an intent, the game crashes.
Anyone can help me fix this?

And should i add myGame activity in my AndroidManifest?

For clear understanding here's my action.

MainActivity > myGame > myCanvas (extends View)

Game Activity:

```
    package com.krazy.androidplay;

    class GameView extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(new myCanvas(this));
    }

    }
```

Canvas code:

```
package com.krazy.androidplay;

public class myCanvas extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();

public myCanvas(Context context) {
    super(context);            
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    canvas.drawRect(33, 60, 77, 77, paint );
    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 77, 60, paint );

}

}
```

Comment: Stack trace would also be helpful.

Comment: how do i get it? will log cat work? log cat is really long though can't put it on here

Comment: Post just the red part of the LogCat. That is actually the stack trace.

Comment: i solved the issue when i actually paid attention to red part so thank you A--C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And should i add myGame activity in my AndroidManifest?

Yes, you should. That's why your app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Use public access identifier in GameView class so it can be launched as an intent.

```
public class GameView extends Activity {
........
}
```